# Method indexOf undefined for the type Marathon

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, indexof

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Marathon {
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
String Time, Point, runnerNum;
File runnersLog = new File("File1");
Scanner Stats = new Scanner(runnersLog);

//while the file has another line...
while (Stats.hasNextLine()) {
//point is the distance from 0 to the first ","
Point = Stats(indexOf(0, ','));
//runnerNum is the distance from the space after the first "," until the second ","
runnerNum = Stats(indexOf(' ' , ','));
//time is the distance from the second space to the end
Time = Stats(indexOf(' '));
}
System.out.println(Point + runnerNum + Time);
Stats.close();
}
}
```

I'm new to coding and taking a class currently, I can't figure out what seems to be the issue here but I'm trying to read and pick out specific information from a separate text file. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Error is self explanatory, Marathon has no method called indexOf()

Comment: Please format the code, this is very hard to read. If you want you can juyt copy-paste from your editor and put three backticks before and after the code.

Answer (score 0):

You call `indexOf` of no explicit instance, so java assumes `this` and here `this` is of type `Marathon` which has no `indexOf` (it would also have to be static since `main` is static)

I assume you want the index of `,` in the current line. For that you have to get said line first using `String line = Stats.nextLine()` and then search for `","` using `line.indexOf(",")`.